# Transpose of matrix inverse: $(AA^T)^{-1}A^Tb \stackrel{?}{=} (A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb$

Tags: matrices, optimization, derivatives, inverse

Given the matrix equation:

$$ x^TA^TA = b^TA $$

I'm trying to find the least squares solution (i.e.; trying to minimize $r=||Ax-b||$). The matrix $A$ is not necessarily symmetric.

When I solve it in following way I find $x$ as:

$$ \begin{array}{rcl}
x^TA^TA &=& b^TA \\
x^T &=& b^TA(A^TA)^{-1} \\
x &=& (AA^T)^{-1}A^Tb
\end{array} $$

But I find a different solution for $x$ when I solve it this way:

$$ \begin{array}{rcl}
x^TA^TA &=& b^TA \\
A^TAx &=& A^Tb \\
x &=& (A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb
\end{array} $$

Apparently the latter one is the correct solution. But what is wrong with the first one? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last step of the first approach should be,
$x = ((A^TA)^{-1})^TA^Tb$

As $A^TA$ is symmetric, its inverse should also be symmetric. (if exist)

Thus $x = (A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb$

Answer (score 2):

In the first derivation the transpose was done wrong on the RHS of the last step, ${(A^TA)^{-1}}^T$ = ${(A^TA)^{T}}^{-1}$ = ${(A^TA)^{-1}}$

Comment: But why? Any references?

Comment: @hkBattousai: The transpose of a product is always the reverse of the transposes: $(AB)^T = B^T A^T$. So $(A^T A)^T = A^T (A^T)^T = A^T A$. And [inverse and transpose commute.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340233/transpose-of-inverse-vs-inverse-of-transpose/340234#340234)