# Prove These Properties of the Pseudoinverse

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, pseudoinverse

Prove these properties of the pseudo inverse:

1) $(AA^*)^{\dagger}={A^{\dagger}}^*A^{\dagger}$;

2) $A^{\dagger}=A^*(AA^*)^{\dagger}$.

I'm quite sure I need to use the four properties of the pseudo inverse, but I'm not exactly sure how. Moreover, I also know that in general we cannot expect $A^{\dagger} A=I$.

Here are the four properties that the pseudoinverse must satisfy as listed in my text:

1) $A X A=A$

2) $X A X = X$

3) $(AX)^*=AX$

4) $(X A)^* = X A$

Please Help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We know that [$*$ of $\dagger$ is equal to $\dagger$ of $*$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/938100/prove-transpose-of-pseudoinverse-commutes).
Note that a simple manipulation of the pseudoinverse properties gives
$$
A=AA^\dagger A=A(A^\dagger A)^*=AA^*A^{\dagger *},
$$
$$
A^*=(AA^*A^{\dagger *})^*=A^\dagger AA^*.
$$
$$
A^\dagger=A^\dagger A A^\dagger=(A^\dagger A)^* A^\dagger=A^*A^{\dagger *}A^\dagger,
$$
$$
A^{\dagger *}=(A^*A^{\dagger *}A^\dagger)^*=A^{\dagger *}A^\dagger A,
$$

You need to verify the four properties, which can be done easily with the above identities:
$$
AA^*(A^{\dagger *}A^\dagger)AA^*=(AA^*A^{\dagger*})(A^\dagger AA^*)=AA^*,
$$
$$
(A^{\dagger *}A^\dagger)AA^*(A^{\dagger *}A^\dagger)=
(A^{\dagger *}A^\dagger A)(A^*A^{\dagger *}A^\dagger)=A^{\dagger *}A^{\dagger}.
$$
The last two properties are simple.
Together, this verifies that $A^{\dagger *}A^\dagger$ is the pseudoinverse of $AA^*$. To prove the second statement, have a look on the third identity above.