# inverse of transpose operator

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, operator-algebras

let us suppose that we have some operator  $T$ which acts as  a  transpose of given matrix in other word

$T(A)=A^T$

question is what is $T^{-1}?$

generally  from this answer
[Transpose of inverse vs inverse of transpose](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340233/transpose-of-inverse-vs-inverse-of-transpose)
its clear that  inverse of  this matrix   $A^T$ is transpose of inverse of this matrix, but when we are talking about operators,  can  should i define  inverse of operator?i  am  following like this way

let $B$  be  inverse operator or

$B(A)=A^{-1}$
and  $T$  be transpose operator, or $T(A)=A^T$

then question comes

what is equal  $B(T)$ ? from the above facts  we got that

$B(T(A))=T(B(A))$

on following video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-X04WJoTDBc

students said that $T^2=I$ or  $T^{-1}=T$  or  inverse of transpose operator is itself transpose operator but how did he got? of course

$A^{-1} A=I$

but from all those things, i can't get point what does mean inverse of operator,  can you make  please clear all those stuff?thanks in advance

## EDITED

about $T^2=I$ that means  that if  we apply  operator twise

$T(T(A))=A$ so we get original matrix, does it means  that  $T^2=I$ ?

Comment: Transposition of matrices is an example of an _involution_, i.e. an operation that is its own inverse. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the inverse of $T$, you mean the map that "undoes" the matrix transpose.  And that's accomplished by transposing again!  So $T^{-1} = T$.  You're right that $T^2 = I$, which means that $T$ is an involution (and yes, $T^2(A)$ is the same thing as $T(T(A))$.)  Finally, the inverse of $T$ doesn't have anything to do with inverting its input argument $A$.  After all, transposition is defined for all square matrices, not just the invertible ones.

Comment: aa i got operation that undo  transpose of  transposed matrix itself transpose