# Let $A, B, C$ be invertible $n \times n$ matrices. Prove that $(A^T B)^{-1} = B^{-1}(A^{-1})^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

> Let $A, B, C$ be invertible $n \times n$ matrices. Prove that $$(A^T B)^{-1} = B^{-1}(A^{-1})^T$$

I'm confused on how to start the problem and was wondering if the answer ends up being $I$?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340233/transpose-of-inverse-vs-inverse-of-transpose/340234#340234

Comment: The 'answer' is a proof.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

$$(CD)^{-1}=D^{-1}C^{-1}$$
$$(A^T)^{-1}=(A^{-1})^T$$

Answer (score 0):

Just multiply:
$$
(A^TB)(B^{-1}(A^{-1})^T)=
A^T(BB^{-1})(A^{-1})^T=
A^T(A^{-1})^T=
(A^{-1}A)^T=I^T=I
$$