# True or False questions about invertible matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, transpose

1. If $A$ is invertible, then $(A^T)^{-1}= (A^{-1})^T $
2. If $A$ and $B$ are invertible, then $A+B$ is also invertible and its inverse is $A^{-1} +B^{-1}$

**Note: Given a matrix $A$, the inverse and the transpose of $A$ are denoted $A^{-1}$ and $A^T$ respectively.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If $A$ is invertible, then $ (A^T)^{-1}= (A^{-1})^T $

- true, see here [Transpose of inverse vs inverse of transpose](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/340233/505767)

2. If $A$ and $B$ are invertible, then $A+B$ is also invertible and its inverse is $A^{-1} +B^{-1}$

- not true, take for example $A=I$ and $B=I$

Answer (score 0):

$1.$ $A$ is invertible $\implies$ $(A^T)^{−1}=(A^{−1})^T$

is true,  because
$$A (A^{-1})= I \implies (A^{-1})^TA^T =(A (A^{-1}))^T=  I^T=I$$

$2.$ $A$ and $B$ are invertible $\implies A+B$ is also invertible and $(A+B)^{−1}=A^{−1}+B^{−1}$

is false, because $(A+B)^{-1}$ may not exist. For example, let
$A=I$ and $B=-I$