# Show that $S=\{ A\in GL_n(K)\mid AJA^t=J\}$ is a subgroup of $GL_n(K)$, where $J\in K^{n\times n}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory, general-linear-group

I have a question about the following problem: show that $$S=\{ A \in GL_n(K) \mid AJA^t = J \}$$ is a subgroup of $GL_n(K)$, where $J\in K^{n\times n}$.

I have shown that the identity element $e$ is part of $S$, but I don't know to prove the second criteria for a subgroup. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It might be worth noting that this is a special case of the general principle that the stabilizer of any element under a group action is a subgroup of the acting group.  In this case, $GL_n(K)$ acts on $K^{n \times n}$ via $A \cdot J = A J A^t$.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Okey, I am sorry, I am new to this site 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use the [one-step subgroup test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test).

Clearly $\varnothing\neq S\subseteq GL_n(K)$.

Let $A,B\in S.$ Then $AJA^t=J=BJB^t$. Observe that
$$\begin{align}
B^{-1}J(B^t)^{-1}&=B^{-1}BJB^t(B^t)^{-1}\\
&=J.
\end{align}$$

We aim to show that $AB^{-1}\in S$. Indeed,

$$\begin{align}
(AB^{-1})J(AB^{-1})^t&=(AB^{-1})J((B^{-1})^tA^t)\\
&=A(B^{-1}J(B^t)^{-1})A^t\tag{1}\\
&=AJA^t\\
&=J.
\end{align}$$

Hence $S\le GL_n(K)$.

---

$(1)$: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/340233/104041).

Comment: Thanks! I understood the proof!

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $A,B \in S$. This means $A,B \in GL_n(K)$ and $AJA^t = BJB^t = J$. We wish to show $AB \in S$. We have $AB \in GL_n(K)$ and
$$(AB)J(AB)^t = (AB)J(B^tA^t) = A(BJB^t)A^t = AJA^t = J$$
so indeed $AB \in S$.

Comment: I feel really dumb... thanks again!

Comment: You still need to show that the inverse of each element is in the subgroup.

Comment: Each element of the proposed subgroup, that is . . .