An elementary matrix multiplication.
I am reading a paper for my thesis, and at some point I think the authors changed $(AA^t)^{-1}A\mathbf v$ into $\mathbf v^t A^{-1}$, where $A$ is an invertible square matrix and $\mathbf v$ a column vector.
I tried to show that it was true and I used the fact that $(A^t)^{-1} = (A^{-1})^t$ but haven't been able to prove it.

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/340233/305862

Does this answer your question? Transpose of inverse vs inverse of transpose

$(AA^T)^{-1}Av=(A^{T})^{-1} A^{-1}Av=(A^T)^{-1}v$
$(A^T)^{-1}v=(v^TA^{-1})^{T}$

Yes, this is correct, I just noticed that this appears in the paper only under the norm sign, that's why the transpose outside the parenthesis was not included. Thank you!

You have
$$
(AA^t)^{-1}Av=(A^{-t}A^{-1})Av=A^{-t}(A^{-1}A)v=A^{-t}v. 
$$
The transpose of this is
$$
(A^{-t}v)^t=v^tA^{-1}. 
$$
